# Convert Milliseconds to SQL datetime

Tags: sql, datetime

How can I convert milliseconds into SQL datetime ?

I transfer the variable start & end like this:

```
 var interval = scheduler.GetSelectedInterval();
 var resourceId = scheduler.GetSelectedResource();
 var start = _aspxDateTimeToMilliseconds(interval.start);
 var end = _aspxDateTimeToMilliseconds(interval.end);
 window.location.href = 
    "FicheAgenda.aspx?Page=ACTION&Mode=Creation&start=" + 
         start + "&end=" + end +"&resourceId=" + resourceId;
```

the output:

```
FicheAgenda.aspx?Page=ACTION&Mode=Creation&start=1334579400000&end=1334584800000&resourceId=24
```

and on FicheAgenda.aspx I want to convert this start & end value into a datetime

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Activity" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnyxConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ID_ACTIVITE], [LIBELLE_ACTIVITE]
                       FROM [ESPTEMPS_ACTIVITE]
                       LEFT JOIN ESPTEMPS_PROGRAMMATION
                ON ESPTEMPS_ACTIVITE.ID_ACTIVITE = ESPTEMPS_PROGRAMMATION.ID_ACTIVITY
                        WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 
                                CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_DEBUT, 3, 2)), 
                                DATEADD(HOUR, 
                                  CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_DEBUT, 1, 2)), 
                                   DATE_DEBUT))
                               < convert(datetime,@StartDate)
                        AND
                              DATEADD(MINUTE, 
                                CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_FIN, 3, 2)), 
                                DATEADD(HOUR, 
                                  CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_FIN, 1, 2)), DATE_FIN))
                              > convert(datetime,@EndDate) ">
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="StartDate" QueryStringField="start" />
     <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="EndDate" QueryStringField="end" />
 </SelectParameters>             
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? (please add appropriate tag)

Comment: What you are going to  compare the millisecond with ? 1-1-1970? if so then you can get a datetime and then insert into sql server

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dateadd` function, for example:

```
dateadd(ms, start, '19800101')
```

where `1980-01-01` would be the "zero" date that you use in your `_aspxDateTimeToMilliseconds` method.

Comment: Thanks you but i got this message error :The data type nvarchar of the argument is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function

Comment: @user609511: Can't you specify that the parameters should be numbers? Otherwise you have to convert the string to a number: `dateadd(ms, cast(start as bigint), '19800101')`

Comment: Thanks you...now i got An arithmetic overflow error occurred while converting expression to data type int.

Comment: @user609511: An `int` can't handle a number larger than 2147483648, that's why I used `bigint` in the example.

Comment: @Guffa are you sure you want to use 1980? Unix epoch started 1970 and most timestamps / milliseconds count from there on.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: It's just an example. You should of course use the same date as the one you use to convert the date into an integer.

Comment: shouldn't it suppose to be `dateadd(ms, start, 0)` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That would be the same as `dateadd(ms, start, '19000101')`, so if you use 1900-01-01 as epoch, that would work. It's however a bit clearer to use the actual date than to implicitly convert the value `0` to the datetime value `'19000101'`.